# running pods and containers in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am fairly new to Kubernates and what I am able to understand so far,

1. cluster is collection of node(s)
2. each node can have a set of running container(s)
3. set of tightly coupled container(s) itself can be grouped together to form a pod (despite of the node in which the container is running).

First of all, am I correct so far?

secondly,  and going through docs about [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-scheduler) says,

> Control Plane component that watches for newly created pods with no assigned node, and selects a node for them to run on.

and docs also says [pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/) are,

> The smallest and simplest Kubernetes object. A Pod represents a set of running containers on your cluster.

My question, rather confusion is since we have already containers running in different nodes, why do we need additional node to run a pod on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. cluster is collection of node(s)
> 2. each node can have a set of running container(s)

You are correct.

> 3. set of tightly coupled container(s) itself can be grouped together to form a pod (despite of the node in which the container is running).

All containers belonging to a pod run on the same node.

> My question, rather confusion is since we have already containers
> running in different nodes, why do we need additional node to run a
> pod on ?

It's not the pod that actually runs. The only things that actually run on your nodes are **containers**. Pod is just a logical grouping of containers and is the basic unit in kubernetes to create a container. (Docker container logo is a whale, a [group of whales is called a pod](https://www.google.com/search?q=group+of+whales&oq=group+of+whales&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) if you want a parallel to remember this). So if the containers that belong to the pod are running, the pod is termed as running.

In the following pod specification, `nginx-container` and `debian-container` containers belong to the pod named `two-containers`. When you create this pod object, `kube-scheduler` will select a node to run this pod (i.e., to run the two containers) and assigns a node to the pod. The `kubelet` running on that node then gets notified and starts the two containers on the node. Since the two containers belong to same pod, they are run in same network namespace.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html

  - name: debian-container
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /pod-data
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "echo Hello from the debian container > /pod-data/index.html"]
```

Comment: Thanks Shashank. Also, can a single node have multiple pods running (configurable somehow by Kubernetes) ?

Comment: Yes. Single node can have multiple pods. By default as of today, the maximum number of pods that can be run on a single node is 110. This can be modified using `maxPods` and `podsPerCore` configuration options of `kubelet`.

Comment: "a group of whales is called a pod" marking these words, :D

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 & 3 are correct.
For number 2 i would say 'Each node can have set pods and each pod can have 1 or more than 1 containers'

and for your last question lets say you create a deployment having 3 pods 2 of them were deployed to node A and it's resources get consumed by 2 of them (No memory or cpu left) but 3rd pod will be in pending state as long as their is no new node to run that pod.

Their is a concept of horizontal pod auto-scaling and cluster auto-scaling
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/ & https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler 
These will further clear your confusion